# What's the base and height of triangle obtained by FT{$\operatorname{sinc}^2(7\pi t)$}?

Tags: fourier-transform, continuous-signals

I'm a little confused about the $\operatorname{sinc}^2(7\pi t)$ function. How do you know the base and height of the triangle produced in the frequency domain only looking at the $\operatorname{sinc}^2(\cdot)$ function? I was trying to solve the integral but I found it was too complicated to solve, when it only produces a triangle.

Comment: Do you like *"ordinary"* frequency in terms of $f$ or *"angular"* frequency in terms of $\omega$?

Comment: I'm assuming this is homework, so I'll give clues.  First -- do you know of any function $f(t)$ whose Fourier transform is of the form $a\ \mathrm{sinc}^2 (b\, \omega)$?  If you _did_ could you see how to use that to solve your problem?